# Can I donate to this site

Tags: discussion

For the few days I’ve been using this sight I have learned quite a bit of material and have been opened to different perspectives. I am not a bot. I genuinely appreciate this community. With that being said; is there a way I can donate to the site to further improve it? Since I don’t know how to code I feel as though it’s the least I could do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The collection of sites associated with ELL.SE are run by a for-profit business, which you can read more about [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/). You wouldn't be donating money to the site, though I'm sure they wouldn't turn down a check mailed to their corporate office. Rather, what you can donate to the site is your time - time spent improving the content on it, by asking good questions, providing good answers, or contributing to the existing content of the site, just like many others here do.